# Render a partial instead or in a flash notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to render a partial or similar in lieu of a simple flash notice. This is how it exists currently:

```
format.html { redirect_to share_url(@doc), notice: "#{@doc.title} has been created. You may #{view_context.link_to('edit', edit_doc_url(@doc))} it further, #{view_context.link_to('finalise', lock_doc_url(@doc))} it, or return #{view_context.link_to('home', root_url)}.".html_safe }
```

I'd like to render a partial or similar instead of the notice so I can customise it more.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do it this way:

```
format.html { render action: "my_error_messages" }
```

Then create a `my_error_messages` action inside the same controller and create a corresponding view and route for it. Then customize the html/haml as you'd like.

Another approach might be to customize the `messages` partial for your flash messages which is most likely being called within your application layout. You'd likely find it in your `apps/views/layouts` directory.